# $x^n\in H$ iff every element of $G/H$ has finite order

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I've written a proof for the above statement and would appreciate any feedback.

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$. We prove for all $x\in G$ there exists $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x^n\in H$ iff every element of $G/H$ has finite order. Now,
\begin{align*}
x^n\in H \\
\Leftrightarrow \forall Hg \in G/H \quad \text{ord}(Hg) \text{ divides } n && \text{by part 2 above} \\
\Leftrightarrow k\cdot \text{ord}(Hg) = n && \text{for some integer } k \\
\Leftrightarrow \text{ord}(Hg) \text{ is finite}. 
\end{align*}

Note: part 2 proved $x^m\in H$ for all $x\in G$ iff order of each element of $G/H$ is a divisor of $m$.

Comment: n depends on x?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp: It has to, in order for the claim to be true. Otherwise a counterexample would be $G=\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ and $H=\{0\}$.

Comment: Then, of course, OP's "proof" is false because he/she uses part 2 in which $n$ does not depend on $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Concise proofs like that may hide problems. One that's clear is at startup: the statement is about “there exists $n$ such that…”.

Moreover the statement is wrong: it should be “there exists $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $n>0$, such that $x^n\in H$”.

Recall the general result: an element $x$ of the group $G$ has finite order if and only if there exists $n>0$ such that $x^n=1$.

Thus an element $xH\in G/H$ has finite order if and only if there exists $n>0$ such that $(xH)^n=1H$. But $(xH)^n=x^nH$ and $yH=1H$ if and only if $y\in H$.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do two directions separately for clarity?

Suppose that for any $\;x\in G\;\;\exists\,n_x\in\Bbb N\;$ such that $\;x^{n_x}\in H\;$ , then in the quotient $\;G/H\;$

$$(xH)^{n_x}:=x^{n_x}H=H\implies\;\text{ord}\,(xH)\le n_x<\infty$$

On the other hand, if every element in $\;G/H\;$ has finite order, then for any $\;x\in G\;$ exists $\;n_x\in\Bbb N\; $ such that

$$H=(xH)^{n_x}=x^{n_x}H\implies x^{n_x}\in H$$